# how to build an array with promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to loop and build an array...starting with "0" and end under '10'...all i'm getting right now is an array size of 1 for each loop even when i is incremented.

```js
(function loop( ii) {
    if (ii < 10) new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout( () => {
            arry.push(ii);
            console.log(ii+" "+arry+' '+arry.length);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    }).then(loop.bind(arry = [], ii+1));
})(0);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: And to answer your question: `arry = []` overrides the global variable at each iteration.

Comment: arry = [] overrides global variables...I get that and that's a question for me as to where to declare it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `arry = []` is the culprit here - each loop is resetting it to an empty array, so when you push to it, it only has a length of one. You will probably need to define the variable outside of the loop, like  this:

```js
var arry = [];

(function loop( ii) {
    if (ii < 10) new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout( () => {
            arry.push(ii);
            console.log(ii+" "+arry+' '+arry.length);
            resolve();
        }, Math.random() * 1000);
    }).then(loop.bind(arry, ii+1));
})(0);
```

Comment: And what's the sense of binding an array to the context of a function?

Comment: @JonasWilms yes I was initially focused on just fixing the stated problem but I agree that if you aren't performing operations on the array using the `this` keyword anywhere, `loop.bind` doesn't make much sense. I'm guessing he wanted to be able to pass a callback to `.then` without needing to define a new function but best practices would certainly be `.then(()=>loop(ii+1))`